# How to obtain surface-current density from current density?

Tags: electromagnetism, vector-fields

**Context**

My problem is related to [1]. I do not dispute the solution in [1], however, it is not helping me to understand the problem that I face. I am working through Example 10.5 in Modern Electrodynamics by Zangwill. This problem pertains to the double-curl equation.

In this example, we integrate $\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\left(\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times \mathbf{A}\right)$ to find $\mathbf{A}$ for a long straight cylindrical wire with radius $a$ which carries a uniform current density $\mathbf{j} = j\,\hat{\mathbf{z}}$. The problem progresses until we arrive to  $\mathbf{A} = A_z(\rho)\,\hat{\mathbf{z}}$, where is given by the case structure in the following equation in terms of an as yet to be determined constant $C$.
\begin{align}
A_z(\rho)
= 
\begin{cases}
-\frac{1}{4}\,\mu_0\,j\,\rho^2, &\rho\leq a;~\text{and}
\\
-\frac{1}{4}\,\mu_0\,j\,a^2  +C \,\ln{\frac{\rho}{a}}, &\rho\geq a.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Zangwill states that, the matching condition
$$\hat{  \mathbf{n}}_2 \times \left[ \mathbf{B}_1  - \mathbf{B}_2 \right] =   \mu_0\,\mathbf{K}(\mathbf{r}_S)  . \tag{10} 
$$
applied at $\rho = a$ fixes $C$. Since, in general,
$\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r}) = 
\boldsymbol{\nabla}  \times  \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r})  
$, therefore, in this case,
$$
\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r}) = 
\begin{cases}
     + \frac{\mu_0\,j}{2}\,\rho       \,\hat{  \boldsymbol{\varphi}}
 , & \rho \leq a;~\text{and}
 \\
-   \frac{  C  }{ \rho}        
  \,\hat{   \boldsymbol{\varphi}    }    , & \rho \geq  a.
\end{cases}
$$
Then, since $\mathbf{K}(\mathbf{r}_S) = K(a,\varphi,z)\,\hat{\mathbf{z}} $, therefore Eq. 10 evaluated at $\rho = a$ results in
$$
\hat{   \boldsymbol{\rho}    }  \times \left[ -   \frac{   C  }{ a}        
     - 
 \frac{\mu_0\,j\,a }{2 }
 \right]\hat{   \boldsymbol{\varphi}    } 
=
     \frac{ -  2\,C - \mu_0\,j\,a^2 }{2\, a}        
\,\hat{   \mathbf{z}    } 
 =   \mu_0\,K(a,\varphi,z)\,\hat{\mathbf{z}} \tag{20}.  
$$
From Eq. 20, we find that the matching condition gives the following equation for $C$:
$$ 
C    
 =  -  \frac{1}{2} \,\mu_0\,j\,a^2 -  a \mu_0\,K(a,\varphi,z) .
\tag{30} $$
Now, Zangwill claims that
$$ 
C    
 =  -  \frac{1}{2} \,\mu_0\,j\,a^2  . \tag{40}
 $$
This means that either the surface-current density is identically zero, or that I have made a mistake along the way.

**Questions**

(1) Smaller question: Have I properly applied the matching conditions so to obtain the correct formula for $C$ (e.g., perhaps I have a sign error).

(2) Larger question: How does one obtain the surface-current density, $\mathbf{K}$, from the current density, $\mathbf{j}$?

**My attempts**

Option 1 (**the correct option**): On the one hand, I would say that the existence of a current density in the bulk of a material does not necessarily imply the existence of surface-current density.

Option 2:

Since $I = \int d\mathbf{S}\cdot \mathbf{j}$ therefore
$$I =  \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty \delta(\rho-a)\,\rho \,d\rho\,d\varphi \,\hat{\mathbf{z}}\cdot j\,\hat{\mathbf{z}}= 
 2\,\pi\,  a \,    j.  $$
This has the outstanding issue that the units are inconsistent on the left- and right-hand side of the equation. Bearing this in mind I come to option 3.

Option 3:

$$K =  \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty \delta(\rho-a)\,\rho \,d\rho\,d\varphi \,\hat{\mathbf{z}}\cdot j\,\hat{\mathbf{z}}= 
 2\,\pi\,  a \,    j.  $$
This has its own outstanding issue. Namely,
upon substitution into Eq. 30, I find that
$$ 
C    
 = \mu_0\,j\,a^2\left[ -  \frac{1}{2}   -  2\,\pi\,    \right],
  $$
which is a result that is inconsistent with Zangwill's answer (i.e., Eq. 40).

Option 4:

I adopt from joshphysics in [1], that
\begin{align}
 \mathbf j = \delta{\left(\rho -a\right)} \,\mathbf K .
\end{align}
However this leaves me scratching my head and asking for relief.

**Bibliography**

[1] [Surface current and current density](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/103803/surface-current-and-current-density)

[2] Zangwill, Modern Electrodynamics, pp. 31-2, 310, 323-4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) You are correct.

(2) Not possible unless it has a Dirac delta part that essentially is just a specification of K. Typically the questions will give it to you, one way or another.

Comment: I understand from your answer that I did not make a sign error or other error. For emphasis, I repeat that the example statement does not---in any way---specify $\mathbf{K}$. Rather, the example  statement only specifies $\mathbf{j}$. So do you think then that $\mathbf{K} =  \mathbf{0}$?

Comment: If you derived Equation (30), then by going to Equation (40) it is clear that Zangwill is telling you that K is zero. I was saying that either they give you K as part of j, a Dirac delta containing part, or they will give it to you as a boundary condition on a surface, and you have to manually deal with it. Or they give you A or B and you differentiate to get K. There is very little chance that you would have to determine it yourself.